# why is the statement in finally block executed despite using return in try block

Tags: java

I don't get why is the statement in finally block being executed despite using return statement in try block. The return statement, as i know, returns the execution to the main.

If am using return in try block that means execution of try ends at that point and control goes into the main. Then why statement in finally is executed?

```
class a
{
 public static void main(String arr[])

{    
 try
 {
 System.out.println("hello1");
 return;
 }

    finally
    {
    System.out.println("hello2");

    }

}
}
```

Comment: `finally` always executes no matter what. But, you can't `return` from a finally block.

Comment: Cause if I'm not mistaken, statements in `finally` clause are always executed, by definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because that's what it's **designed** to do. It is **not** like `catch (...)` in C++ (which only executes if not caught elsewhere).

`finally` can be very useful in cleaning up resources: it is one way that Java introduces RAII-type features that are more prevalent in other languages like C++ (via destructors). Java more naturally performs clean-up via the garbage collector but `finally` permits an alternative approach.

Comment: RAII-type language??????

Comment: Yeah that was a taxomonist's indulgence: I've amended.

Comment: @IRON-MAN, Resource Acquisition Is... Oh, go Google it!  RAII is a common C++ pattern where, among other things, you use the destructor of a local variable to clean up when a function exits.

Comment: the equivalent in C++ is the destructor of any local objects.

Answer (score 3):

Regardless of what you are doing in `try`, the finally block always executes even though you return from your try  block.

From [`finally`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html) docs

> The runtime system always executes the statements within the finally block **regardless** of what happens within the try block. So it's the perfect place to perform cleanup.

<sub>Fun learning: As you are talking about return and try-finally. Just put return in try and again return in finally. And see what happens :)</sub>

Comment: @IRON-MAN, Re fun learning:  Also fun to see what happens if the try block throws an exception that is not caught in any catch block _and_ the finally also throws an exception.  Hint:  Allowing a finally block to throw is considered to be Bad Style.

Comment: Have even more fun: see what happens if you use System.Exit.

Comment: @Bathsheba My god. I killed JVM. Police on their way ;).

Answer (score 1):

Finally will always execute. You could try using some conditional (if, else) statements instead.

Answer (score 0):

> why is the statement in finally block executed despite using return in try block

By design. The whole point of a `finally` block is that *it doesn't matter* how you leave the `try` block, the code in `finally` will be run. Full stop. (Well, unless you crash the JVM.)